# Finding a function $f(x)$ with value $-1$, $0$, or $1$ based on $x$ being negative, $0$, or positive, respectively

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I was looking for a simple function that converts an integer in the following way:$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if } x >0\\
0 & \text{if } x=0\\
-1 & \text{if } x < 0 \end{cases}$$

Is there a simple function that does this?

Edit: Sorry for the confusion of the word "simple" Perhaps I should have said a function that does not involve 'if logic' (bear with me, i'm not a mathmagician) but is within reason to replace the existing 'if logic' because it is not a large formula.

Comment: What do you mean by simple? What you've written seems simple enough to me.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "simple" - you seem to have defined a function which does the job.

Comment: No matter how else it is written, it will still be the same function.

Comment: I will update my question to define simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't say that there's a simpler function other than what you've already posted, but it could be useful to know that this function is also referred to as the [sign or signum function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), written $sgn(x)$.

Comment: LaTeX/math tip: The sign function is supposed to be written in upright roman (like $\sin$ and friends) with e.g. `\operatorname{sgn}`. When one uses `$sgn$` the output looks like the product of three variables called s, g and n.

Comment: Thanks much for the sgn(x), not to find out if my language supports that out of the box ;)

Answer (score 5):

This is just a curiosity since it involves taking a limit, but how about
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan(tx).
\end{equation}
It does the right things, giving for example $f(0)=0$ as the limiting value of the constant $\arctan(t0)=0$, and working at nonzero $x$ by using the positive and negative asymptotes of $\arctan(tx)$, and dividing by the absolute value $\pi/2$ of the limit.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe, $f(x):=\frac{|x|}{x}$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly simpler: For $x=0$, set $f(x)=x$ ;otherwise set $f(x)=\dfrac{|x|}x$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), in terms of which your $f(x)=2H(x)-1$ (with the convention, sometimes but not always used, that $H(0)=\frac 12$) but it is not really different from what you wrote.

Comment: Note that 2H(0)-1=1 instead of 0 (at least with the definition of the Heaviside function on the page you linked to).

Comment: @did:  No, it shows $H(0)=\frac 12$ in the graph.

Comment: The caption of the graph you mention reads *The Heaviside step function*, **using the half-maximum convention**, and the main text uses the, at least as common, convention that H(0)=1. Omitting these details from your answer is misleading (and I find rather odd, I must say, the dismissive tone of your last comment... are we trying to reach exact, helpful, non ambiguous answers or what?).